# spark application failing, after mapreduce success

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hue

I am doing Spark Application in Hue Workflow (Oozie).(AWS EMR)

```
Hadoop EMR 2.7.3
Hive 2.3.0
Hue 3.12.0
Spark 2.2.0
```

The execution time of the Job takes about 3 hours 30 minutes.

Spark application job operations are success.

However, an error occurs when the JobHistoryEventHandler writes the job history event of MRAppMaster directly to DFS in the staging directory and then moves it to done-dir.

I have set the following options when creating a SparkSession, but I get the same error.

```
.config("spark.speculation", "false")
.config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.map.speculative", "false")
.config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.reduce.speculative", "false")
```

The file seems to be deleted before the JobHistory Log is completely written.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Please.

```
2019-04-25 17:56:37,688 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices  - Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
2019-04-25 17:56:37,689 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend  - Stopped
2019-04-25 17:56:37,696 [dispatcher-event-loop-11] INFO  org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint  - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2019-04-25 17:56:37,722 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore  - MemoryStore cleared
2019-04-25 17:56:37,723 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager  - BlockManager stopped
2019-04-25 17:56:37,728 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster  - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2019-04-25 17:56:37,732 [dispatcher-event-loop-3] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint  - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2019-04-25 17:56:37,734 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Successfully stopped SparkContext

<<< Invocation of Spark command completed <<<

Hadoop Job IDs executed by Spark: job_1555401240260_3212


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://ip-11-200-20-303.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal:8020/user/admin/oozie-oozi/0005534-190307151834967-oozie-oozi-W/spark-e891--spark/action-data.seq
2019-04-25 17:56:39,498 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory  - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2019-04-25 17:56:39,499 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool  - Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
Successfully reset security manager from org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherSecurityManager@12b1c419 to null

Oozie Launcher ends

2019-04-25 17:56:39,553 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl  - Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,562 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task:attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2019-04-25 17:56:39,597 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl  - Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,597 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl  - Done acknowledgement from attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,598 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task 'attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0' done.
2019-04-25 17:56:39,600 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl  - attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from RUNNING to SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP
2019-04-25 17:56:39,601 [uber-EventHandler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher  - Processing the event EventType: CONTAINER_REMOTE_CLEANUP for container container_1555401240260_3211_01_000001 taskAttempt attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,601 [uber-EventHandler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher  - canceling the task attempt attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,621 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher  - Unable to delete unexpected local file/dir .action.xml.crc: insufficient permissions?
2019-04-25 17:56:39,623 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl  - attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP to SUCCEEDED
2019-04-25 17:56:39,633 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl  - Task succeeded with attempt attempt_1555401240260_3211_m_000000_0
2019-04-25 17:56:39,635 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl  - task_1555401240260_3211_m_000000 Task Transitioned from RUNNING to SUCCEEDED
2019-04-25 17:56:39,638 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl  - Num completed Tasks: 1
2019-04-25 17:56:39,639 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl  - job_1555401240260_3211Job Transitioned from RUNNING to COMMITTING
2019-04-25 17:56:39,639 [CommitterEvent Processor #1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler  - Processing the event EventType: JOB_COMMIT
2019-04-25 17:56:39,642 [Thread-85] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on 
 (inode 1387896): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-2005393980_1 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
2019-04-25 17:56:39,643 [eventHandlingThread] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient  - Error while syncing
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/admin/.staging/job_1555401240260_3211/job_1555401240260_3211_1.jhist (inode 1387896): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-2005393980_1 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)

2019-04-25 17:56:39,647 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl  - Calling handler for JobFinishedEvent 
2019-04-25 17:56:39,648 [AsyncDispatcher event handler] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl  - job_1555401240260_3211Job Transitioned from COMMITTING to SUCCEEDED
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster  - We are finishing cleanly so this is the last retry
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster  - Notify RMCommunicator isAMLastRetry: true
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator  - RMCommunicator notified that shouldUnregistered is: true
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster  - Notify JHEH isAMLastRetry: true
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler  - JobHistoryEventHandler notified that forceJobCompletion is true
2019-04-25 17:56:39,649 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster  - Calling stop for all the services
2019-04-25 17:56:39,650 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler  - Stopping JobHistoryEventHandler. Size of the outstanding queue size is 2
2019-04-25 17:56:39,650 [Thread-953] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler  - In stop, writing event TASK_FINISHED
2019-04-25 17:56:39,653 [Thread-953] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler  - Error writing History Event: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.TaskFinishedEvent@31ccabfb
```

Comment: This error appears as LeaseExpiredException (file does not exist).

Comment: `LeaseExpiredException` typically means that a process opened a HDFS file -- with **exclusive** write lock _(lease)_ -- but neglected to write or do any kind of keep-alive on that file for too long, hence the DataNode in charge of replica #1 assumed a disconnect and revoked the lock / lease. Looks like either a Spark bug or an application-level bug.

Comment: @ Samson Scharfrichter - Can you tell me which settings can fix the error?

Comment: Do you think I'm a magician? Sorry, I'm not.